# UIpickerView Swift 3 Cannot multiply the value

Tags: swift, swift3, double, uipickerview

Im trying to get the pickerViews value and multiply It In a Button action, but its giving me errors, i tried toons of different ideas. but sadly I still didnt accomplish what I'm trying to get done, i have updated the code for better understanding. 
- Multiply picker views value and show it in a textview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var perlol: UILabel!
var distribTopp:Array = [String]()
var distribBottomm:Array = [String]()
var priceLabell:Array = [String]()
var titleBarr:Array = [String]()
var iconeImage:Array = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    titleBarr = ["Fees","","","Profit","Calculations",""]

    distribTopp = ["Paypal Fee","Ebay Fee","Feeless Price","Profit","Price Increase","Percent Increase"]

    distribBottomm = ["Takes 2.9% + $0.30","Takes 10%","Price Without Fees","Profit From Original Price","How much USD Added","Percentage of Increased Price"]

    priceLabell = ["$0.00","$0.00","$0.00","$0.00","$0.00","0.00%"]

    iconeImage = [UIImage(named: "home")!,UIImage(named: "home")!,UIImage(named: "home")!,UIImage(named: "home")!,UIImage(named: "home")!,UIImage(named: "home")!
    ]

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

var percentagesPicker = ["10%","20%","30%","40%","50%"]

// DataSource
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return percentagesPicker.count
}

// Delegate

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


    return percentagesPicker[row]

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

  //  var thirtyone = Double(percentagesPicker[row])


    perlol?.text! = percentagesPicker[row]

    if perlol?.text! == "10%"{

        let thirty = Double(3000/10000)
        perlol?.text = String(thirty)
    }
    if perlol?.text! == "20%"{

        perlol?.text = String(thirty)
    }
    if perlol?.text! == "30%"{

        perlol?.text = String(thirty)
    }
    if perlol?.text! == "40%"{

        perlol?.text = String(thirty)
    }
    if perlol?.text! == "50%"{

        perlol?.text = String(thirty)
    }

    print(percentagesPicker[row])
    print(perlol)


}


// var percenta = self.percentagesPicker[row]

var Duration = Double(0.30)
var ebayfeess = Double(0.1)
var paypalfeess = Double(0.029)
var profitsss = Double(100)
var thirty = Double(3000/10000)


@IBAction func clearBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    priceLabell = ["$0.00","$0.00","$0.00","$0.00","$0.00","0.00%"]
    myPrice.text = String("0.00")
    productPrice.text = String("")

}

@IBAction func goCalcul(_ sender: Any) {



    let productnum = Double(productPrice.text!)! // Original Price
    let feess = Double(productnum * thirty + productnum) //New Listing Price
    let paypalfs = Double(paypalfeess * feess + Duration)//Paypal  Fees
    let ebayfs = Double(ebayfeess * feess) // Ebay Fee
    let profitss = Double(((feess/productnum) * profitsss) - profitsss) //Percent
    let priceIncrease = Double(productnum * 3000/10000) // Price Increase
    let buying = Double(feess - paypalfs - ebayfs) // Left with
    let profitnow = Double(buying - productnum) // Profit

    let decimalPaypal = NSString(format: "%.2f", paypalfs)
    let decimalebay = NSString(format: "%.2f", ebayfs)
    let decimalbuying = NSString(format: "%.2f", buying)
    let decimalProfit = NSString(format: "%.2f", profitnow)
    let decimalprice = NSString(format: "%.2f", priceIncrease)
    let decimaloriginal = NSString(format: "%.2f", feess)
   // let l = String(perlol?.text)
    myPrice.text = String(decimaloriginal)
    //perlol.text = Double(perlol?.text)
    //print(perlol.text)

    priceLabell = [String("-$\(decimalPaypal)"),String("-$\(decimalebay)"), String("$\(decimalbuying)"), String("+$\(decimalProfit)"), String("+$\(decimalprice)"),String("+\(profitss)%")]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return distribTopp.count & distribBottomm.count & titleBarr.count & priceLabell.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell") as! MenuTableViewCell
    cell.imgLbl.image = iconeImage[indexPath.row]
    cell.describTop.text! = distribTopp[indexPath.row]
    cell.describBottom.text! = distribBottomm[indexPath.row]
    cell.priceLabel.text! = priceLabell[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleBar.text! = titleBarr[indexPath.row]


    if cell.describTop.text! == "Paypal Fee"
    {
        cell.priceLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
    if cell.describTop.text! == "Feeless Price"
    {
        cell.priceLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    if cell.describTop.text! == "Profit"
    {
        cell.priceLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
    }

    if cell.describTop.text! == "Price Increase"
    {
        cell.priceLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
    }

    if cell.describTop.text! == "Percent Increase"
    {
        cell.priceLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
    if cell.describTop.text! == "Ebay Fee"
    {
        cell.priceLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell:MenuTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    if cell.describTop.text! == "Paypal Fee"
    {

    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: You're multiplying a `Double` with a `UILabel`?

Comment: i have updated the code, thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is "perlol" in the "goCalcul" method? It appears to be a label based on its usage in the UIPickerView delegate method. And if yes, shouldn't you take the text value from the label and convert it to some sort of a percentage value before you do the multiplication?

Comment: that is what im trying to do :/ i cant get it to work

Comment: What is the error message you get? And is it possible for you to upload a sample project somewhere so that I can download and see what is going on? If you can upload a project, then let me know once you've done that and I'll take a look.

Comment: can i get your email? i will send it on there

Comment: You can send it to ff-stack (at) farook (dot) org

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be helpful. What errors are you getting?

My guess is that you have not set the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate) or [datasource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource) for your UIPickerView. After you have implemented them, your ViewController class definition will look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
```

Command click on the protocols to see the functions that you can/will need to implement.